# bash scripting "top: -p requires argument"

Tags: linux, bash

In my scripting file i have

```
top -p $(pgrep -d',' java)
```

but when i run it i just get the error

```
top: -p requires argument
```

what the script will do is in top, it will only show the process with the name of java. ive looked around for a few different things and ive tried

```
top $(-p) $(pgrep -d',' java)
```

i dont know scripting that well to know exactly what this does. but i do have vague understanding of scripting from googleing and a few bash tuts..

Comment: That means `pgrep` didn't find any running processes and became an empty string so you ended up running `top -p`.

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks! makes a lot of since now that i know that. submit as answer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `pgrep` finds no such process, it will exit with a non-zero exit status in addition to producing no output. You can take advantage of this to run `top` only if the `pgrep` succeeds.

```
pid=$(pgrep -d, java) && top -p $pid
```

Answer (score 0):

just run top if pgrep returns some pids
like this:

```
pids=$(pgrep -d, java)
[ ! -z "$pids" ] && top -p $pids
```

For an alternative use xargs like this:

```
pgrep -d, java | xargs --no-run-if-empty top -bp
```